# Создание PDF файла средствами php

Tags: php, битрикс, pdf

Добрый день. Необходимо создать pdf документ в корзине пользователя для сайта на системе управления 1С-Битрикс. Начал с основ, но сразу же столкнулся с [проблемой](http://pdf.itfokos.ru/pdf.php) Для создания pdf документа использую библиотеку FPDF. Пример моего файла:

```
<?php
define('FPDF_FONTPATH','/home/host1510082/itfokos.ru/htdocs/pdf/font/');
require( 'fpdf.php' );

$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',72);
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Cell(40,10,"Hello World!",15);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте выставить в начале `header('Content-type: application/pdf');` а так же уберите в конце `?>`

Comment: Спасибо, ваш совет помог.

Comment: ?> в принципе убирать не требуется, главное, чтобы после этой конструкции не было символов, в том числе пробельных )

Comment: Так то да, но PSR-2 не просто так придумали